# custom nagios notification type

Tags: monitoring, nagios

Is it possible to pass a notification message from nagios to a python script that will dispatch a custom notification, instead of nagios sending email or an sms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  Here's an example [using Skype for notification](http://wiki.nagios.org/index.php/SkypeSmsNotification).

Generally, you define a command that will execute the python script, then use that command for the host_notification_commands or service_notification_commands options in the contact definition.

Comment: The link now redirects to the main Nagios Wiki page. Could you please include the essential parts of the original page to this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  You simply set up a command to run for the notification and associate it with a contact (see http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/notifications.html, http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#contact and http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#command for details)